# Facebook Business LIKE box is giving an Open Graph error

Tags: facebook, meta-tags

> You supplied an Open Graph type via
>   one of the supported meta tags, but
>   the type you specified "link" is not
>   valid.

The above is the error I get when the "LIKE" button is clicked.

I tried to set all sorts of OG meta tags. You can see the code live at http://luxe.sonikastudios.com

I looked at many different forums etc. but no clear answer is given. I don't even have an og type "link" specified.

I put my page through the linter provided by Facebook (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) and I don't see any errors coming up as far as I can tell (but then I don't even know what this screen is supposed to look like in case there is an error).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be a known FB Bug: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/process_bug.cgi

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't like your `<meta property="fb:link">` tag. Where did you get it from?

Just remove everything and leave only required params [listed here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like). I would also recommend setting type to `article`. See if that works. If it does then start adding new params one by one until it fails.

Comment: Doesn't work.. removed the fb:link parameter and changed it to article. 

The link you listed is for JUST the "like" button being embedded. This is a whole widget sitting within an iFrame, and I followed the guidelines from one of the Facebook pages, copy-pasted the whole block, and modified the contents of the meta tags... :(

Comment: So.. I gave up, left the code as-is.. and after a few days it started working. Weird. Maybe FB has some odd way of caching the source pages, and needs some time to work it out?

Comment: @jeffkee no idea. facebook is not exactly know as the most stable system out there.